# How to test a method that uses Activator.CreateInstance(...)?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, debugging, clr

I'm writing a test for the following method:

```
public IAnInterface Instantiator()
{
    var type = Type.GetType(A_CONSTANT_STRING);
    return (IAnInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

When the test is running, the type obtained from the `Type.GetType(...)` method is null. My questions are:

1. The `null` is being returned because not all the types are loaded(?) when the tests are executed?
2. How to overcome this problem? Actually I want to test if the required type has been returned.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding a reference to the project where the type specified at `A_CONSTANT_STRING` is located.

Answer (score 1):

As @Krekkon already mentioned [Type.GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method requires the following string:

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

For question #2: You will not be able to test whether the type has been returned because of the static call to [Type.GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx). If you can change the code you could introduce an interface that is responsible for type resolving and represents a facades of the static GetType method call:

```
interface ITypeResolver
{
  Type GetType(string typeName);
}

class SomeClass
{
  private readonly ITypeResolver typeResolver = ...;

  public IAnInterface Instantiator()
  {
    var type = this.typeResolver.GetType(A_CONSTANT_STRING);
    return (IAnInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  }
}
```

Using an interface you are able to mock the `ITypeResolver` and also test the implementation of `ITypeResolver` interface in Isolation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var type = Type.GetType("namespace.qualified.TypeName");
```

Answer (score -1):

What assembly is your type defined in? Assuming your method is in the same assembly as the type you are looking for, try:

```
var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .First(t => t.Name == A_CONSTANT_STRING);

return (IAnInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: I am not suggesting you do that. I was only assuming fo rth esake of simplicity that you might be running your test in the same assembly. If you are not, you still want to reference the assembly where you want to look for your type...